# Circle properties (and methods?)

Tags: geometry

I have been doing a lot of object-oriented programming lately, so my question is a little related to it.

I was teaching mathematics (geometry) to my friend and I came up with a question:

In Scala we would have circle probably defined as this:

> class Circle(val radius: Double) {
>
> def area = π*radius^2
>
> def diameter = 2*radius
>
> ...
>
> }

So Circle class has a property name "radius" and methods (area, diameter, etc.) which use "radius" in calculations.

Are these all "properties" of a circle in mathematics, or are there different terms for radius (since everything is defined by radius) and methods such as an area?

Comment: A circle is defined fully its radius... if you fix a coordinate system you need a centre and a radius.

Answer (score 1):

From a programmer's point of view, these are properties if you can invoke them without a (void) argument list.

Like print `MyCircle.Area`, rather than `MyCircle.Area()`, which would be a method.

If the properties are wrapped, one could also consider that `GetArea()` is a property, in the same sense as `GetRadius()`.

In your description, `Area` seems to be a read-only property (hence no setter). But it could be otherwise, by defining

```
def SetArea(val Area: Double) radius= sqrt(Area / π)
```

Comment: I don't known the Scala syntax.